# Stop aria2c from parsing torrent file

Tags: aria2

When I download a torrent file with aria2c, it always try to parse it and add a torrent task, but all I want is get that file.

Is it possible to stop aria2c from doing so? I didn't seem to find an option in manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
aria2c "${URL}" --follow-torrent=false
```

From [`aria2`'s manual](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html):

> `--follow-torrent=true|false|mem` - If `true` or `mem` is specified, when a file whose suffix is `.torrent` or content type is `application/x-bittorrent` is downloaded, `aria2` parses it as a `torrent` file and downloads files mentioned in it. If `mem` is specified, a `torrent` file is not written to the disk, but is just kept in memory. If `false` is specified, the `.torrent` file is downloaded to the disk, but is not parsed as a `torrent` and its contents are not downloaded.

```
Default: true
```